# Cant get AngularJS site running in Docker Container

Tags: angularjs, node.js, docker, boot2docker

I have an angular site that I am attempting to run in a docker container (only through boot2docker right now).

The `Dockerfile` looks like the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install -y npm

# Set in what directory commands will run
WORKDIR /home/app

# Put all our code inside that directory that lives in the container
ADD . /home/app

RUN sudo npm install && \
    sudo npm install -g grunt-cli

#Need to do this for npm and bower
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

# Install dependencies
RUN sudo npm install -g bower && \
    sudo npm install -g grunt-cli && \
    sudo npm install && \
    bower install --config.interactive=false --allow-root

EXPOSE 9000

# The command to run our app when the container is run
ENTRYPOINT ["npm","start"]
```

When I run `docker build -t web-app .` the image builds fine.

And I run the following command to star the container

```
docker run --name my-web-app -p 9000:9000 -d web-app
```

If I run `docker logs` I can see that it is working...

```
> sb-admin@0.0.0 start /home/app
> grunt serve

Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Cleaning .tmp...OK

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

    Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
    Copied 3 files

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2015-07-27 05:04:02 UTC)
    loading tasks  2ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 18%
    copy:styles    9ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 82%
    Total 11ms

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
File .tmp/styles/main.css created.
File .tmp/styles/sb-admin-2.css created.
File .tmp/styles/timeline.css created.

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

If I run `npm start` manually (not in the container, just on my local) the site is available at `http://localhost:9000`, but when I navigate to the IP address that I get from `IP=$(boot2docker ip)` I get a connection refused.

The same happens if I SSH into the container and run any of the following:

```
IP=$(docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" my-web-app)
curl -X GET $IP:9000
```

I feel like I have ran hundres of containers like this and accessed them fine, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I figured out the issue and I will post it once I am able to.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your hostname to `0.0.0.0` when working inside a container instead of localhost.

For example, we use docker for developing Angular applications with NPM, Bower & Grunt build stack. We use `grunt serve` task while developing. To make this work in a container we have created a `container` target in the `connect` task taht overrides default settings.

It looks something similar to this:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  container: {
    options: {
      hostname: '0.0.0.0',
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
              '/bower_components',
              connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  ...
 }
```

Here `container` target is a copy of the `livereload` target but with the `hostname` overriden.

Depending on the the NPM module you are using to serve your application you may be able to configure a hostname or the module will be created either on `localhost` or listening on all IP addresses on the local machine: `0.0.0.0`.